# Detect the time overlap in a list in Python?

Tags: python, date, date-range

I have a list of datetime.time as follows. The max length of this list is always <=4. The date.time values are showing a start and end time range. I am trying to find an efficient way in Python to return a list with a single element that contains the overlap times. For example, in the case the function should return [datetime.time(1, 30), datetime.time(5, 30)]. Overlap is considered only if the end times are the same.

```
times = [[datetime.time(15, 30), datetime.time(17, 0)], [datetime.time(23, 0), datetime.time(5, 30)], [datetime.time(1, 30), datetime.time(5, 30)]]
```

Comment: What does the second element in `times` represent? Can dates wrap over to the next day?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark the first element in each list is the start time and the second element in each list is the end time. Dates can wrap over to the next day. For example, in [datetime.time(23, 0), datetime.time(5, 30)], the start is at 23:00PM end is the next day 5:30AM.

Comment: @trincot no overlap since end times are different.

Comment: @trincot agree. I just edited the question. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to group the time spans by their end time, and when there is more than one span in the same group, get the one that is the shortest and add it to the result.

There are several ways to do that, and several modules that could help with that.

Here is one way:

```
from datetime import time
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce, partial

def nearest(end, a, b):
    return min(a, b) if (a < end) != (b < end) else max(a, b)

def shortest_suffix(times):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for start, end in times:
        d[end].append(start)
    return [
        [reduce(partial(nearest, end), starts), end]
            for end, starts in d.items()
                if len(starts) > 1
    ]

# demo run
times = [[time(15, 30), time(17, 0)], 
         [time(23, 0), time(5, 30)], 
         [time(1, 30), time(5, 30)]]

print(shortest_suffix(times))  # [[datetime.time(1, 30), datetime.time(5, 30)]]
```